# Simple Forum Software?

Tags: forum, phpbb, bbpress, punbb

I'm looking for extremely simple forum software.

Something that simply allows a user to create an account, make a post, and for users to comment on that post.

No HTML, no user profiles, no private message, no bloat. Just software for simple postings. Almost borderline blog software that allows user created accounts.

I've looked at the following software and they have way more features, functionality and bloat than I want:

- **bbPress** (close, but even *more* simple ... and from the lastest dev post, apparrently bbPress is being dropped for a WordPress plugin)
- **Vanilla**
- **SMF**
- **PunBB** / **FluxBB**
- **phpBB**

Does anyone know of any good simple forum software?

---

**UPDATE**

I just found an example forum that is great in being simple. It's [Street Easy's forum](http://streeteasy.com/nyc/talk). I'd love to know what underlining software they are using. This is nearly exactly what I want. The only thing I'd remove is that it has "Categories/Tags". I don't need that. If the Category/Tag could be removed, functionality - this is exactly what I want.

**UPDATE 2**

Still no answers :(

Comment: In my view, that would be something in the spirit of StackOverflow. I **don't mean the questions**, I mean using OpenID (so you can pass off user management to the OpenID provider and not bother with forgotten passwords) and Markdown (not something ugly like bbcode). +1 from me.

Comment: I'd use modified version on PunBB or FluxBB (if you want a faster system).

Comment: @TheLifelessOne, is there a supported project that is a stripped down version of PunBB/FluxBB?

Comment: @TeddyH - Not that I'm currently aware of, though the two teams may be able to help make a stripped down version (at the very least, tell you what not to poke at.)

Comment: @TheLifelessOne, I'm looking for forum software available **now** for use. Any other recommendations?

Comment: @TeddyH - Might not be exactly what your looking for, but I found this on Google: http://www.minibb.com/

Comment: @TheLifelessOne, thanks for the link but minibb.com, after using the demo, appears to be somewhere between bbPress (more features) and PunBB (less features).  I'm looking for something even **simpler** than bbPress.

Comment: Not suitable for Super User either as it's for a web based solution.

Comment: How is this **off-topic** ???  It's software related asking about web-based forum software.

Comment: **IF this is off-topic, then literally every single "Related" topic on the sidebar listed also needs to be closed. This is bogus.**

Comment: I still don't understand why this topic was closed

Comment: @TeddyH: Although it's software-related, it's not programming-related. I admit that the line can be vague, but this is clearly on the "usage related", hence "not programming related" side of it. (If you ever do find the answer, please post back here! I fav'd this question because I'd like such a piece of software too.)

Comment: Since this topic is closed and I can't add an answer, I shall post a comment instead. The No-nonsense forum software (http://camendesign.co.uk/code/nononsense_forum) might do what you want. It is designed to remove communication barriers.